# How do I link different values in a column according to one value of another field?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Sorry for the misspecification of the question , but the problem is not easy to be explained in few words, also given I am not an expert in SQL.

I have a dataset containing three field:

```
ID   SECTOR      GRADE 
1      aaa       Junior
2      aaa       Senior
3      aaa       Director1
4      bbb       Junior
5      bbb       Senior
6      bbb       Director2
```

ID refers to different persons, and the grade, obviously the grade within the organisation.

I am trying to have the following output by adding another column describing the director for each ID. i.e For sector 'aaa' we have 'Director1' , for sector 'bbb' we have 'Director2'. therefore I would like to have:

```
ID   SECTOR       GRADE       DIRECTOR  
1      aaa       Junior        Director1
2      aaa       Senior        Director1
3      aaa       Director1     director1
4      bbb       Junior        Director2
5      bbb       Senior        Director2
6      bbb       Director2     Director2
```

I could only think about a cursor but I am sure there Is a simple way to do so.

The structure is:

```
SELECT R.ID, D.SECTOR, D.Grade
FROM Resource
LEFT JOIN D.Dimension on D.ID=R.ID
```

Comment: Are you sure that there is only **one** director? What if there are multiple?

Comment: For each sector I only have one director, always.

Comment: What SQL dialect are you using? MySQL, PostgreSQL,...?

Comment: Am using MSSQL (Microsoft SQL Server 2008)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can construct an temporary table of directors with:

```
SELECT D.SECTOR AS SECTOR, D.Grade AS DIRECTOR
FROM D.Dimension
WHERE D.Grade LIKE 'Director%'
```

and then you can `JOIN` your original query with the "sector to director" table:

```
SELECT R.ID, D.SECTOR, D.Grade, Dir.DIRECTOR
FROM Resource
LEFT JOIN D.Dimension on D.ID=R.ID
JOIN (
    SELECT D.SECTOR AS SECTOR, D.Grade AS DIRECTOR
    FROM D.Dimension
    WHERE D.Grade LIKE 'Director%'
) AS Dir ON Dir.SECTOR = D.SECTOR
```